# Android ActionBar Search Field

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I have a standard search EditText in my ActionBar, triggered by a touch on a little magnifying glass icon. I can cache the user's search string using the OnQueryTextListener. I want to put that string back into the EditText when the user touches the icon a second time.

I'm using ABS (soon to abandon), targeting 8-19.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

With a normal action bar (you'll have to find the different variation with ABS, not sure if my answer will apply completely with that library).

SearchView is a widget that can be inflated in the options menu, so what I do is inflate a menu using an XML containing an action view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_user"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/magnifing_glass"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Search Users"/>

</menu>
```

Next, when inflating the action view, set your listeners, and use a global variable to save the previous search.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);


        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search_user);

            //Keep a global variable of this so you can set it within the next listener
            SearchView user_search = (SearchView) search.getActionView();

        user_search.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                global_variable = query;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Finally, in a second listener, set the text of the global variable to your previous query when the action view expands.

```
//This is set on the menu item
search.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do something when collapsed
            return true;       // Return true to collapse action view
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            user_search.setQuery(global_variable, false);
            return true;      // Return true to expand action view
        }
    });
```